# Configuring Apache James with Spring

Tags: java, spring, email, james

I use Apache James to send email in my project , For it I run apache james server on my machine . I was looking if I can configure james with spring as I am using spring framework and everything is configured in it . Also Is it capable of sending multipart message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can configure james with spring.

1. You just need to create an account on james
2. Use the james user account on spring email